# Running Neural Net in VSCode using an External CUDA Compatible GPU

Tags: visual-studio-code, cuda, gpu

Sorry if this is not technically clear I am very new to GPU stuff. I am trying to run an ML model on my local computer but I am pretty sure the code requires use of CUDA and thus an external GPU. I am pretty sure about the need for a GPU because of this error I get:
File /opt/miniconda3/envs/diffdock_pp/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/cuda/**init**.py", line 408, in set_device
torch._C._cuda_setDevice(device)
AttributeError: module 'torch._C' has no attribute '_cuda_setDevice'
Is there any way I can pay to ssh into an external GPU from vscode, using Jupyter or colab or something? What can I look at to get a better understanding of this? I have an M1 chip if that matters.

Comment: There is no CUDA support on modern Mac systems (intel or arm) and no way of using an “external” GPU in whatever you way you imagined. There are CUDA GPU accelerated cloud offerings available from a number of vendors, but you are in the wrong place to ask about those